# Laravel 5.8 cookie value is different from what I set

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I am trying to upgrade from Laravel 4.2 to 5.8, I saw that I can still use Cookie::forever and Cookie::get to work with cookie so I didnt had to change my code but the weird thing is that the cookie is set with the correct name but his value is very different (encrypted I guess) from what I set, I am doing this  :

```
// login page
$cookie = Cookie::forever('session_id', 'test');        
return redirect('/')->withCookie($cookie);

// index page
$cookie = Cookie::get('session_id'); 
echo $cookie; // return something like eyJpdiI6ImZqdnF2NkVkbVc4VGJiS3FSYzk4VWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTkgrVW
```

This was working fine on 4.2, did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223542/561670, its a decrypt issue, this is working :

```
\Crypt::decryptString(Cookie::get('session_id'))
```